# Split text into words but consider comma as word

Tags: php, explode

I would like to get each word of this text but need to consider comma as a separate word, in PHP:

My input text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

My wanted array:

```
array[0] => "Lorem"
array[1] => "ipsum"
array[2] => "dolor"
array[3] => "sit"
array[4] => "amet"
array[5] => ","
array[6] => "consectetuer"
array[7] => "adipiscing"
array[8] => "elit"
array[9] => "."
```

What I get with `explode(" ", $text)` is:

```
array[0] => "Lorem"
array[1] => "ipsum"
array[2] => "dolor"
array[3] => "sit"
array[4] => "amet,"
array[5] => "consectetuer"
array[6] => "adipiscing"
array[7] => "elit."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the comma with a space+comma+space ',' -> ' , '

```
$newSentence = str_replace("," , " , " , $theSentence);  
$arr = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $newSentence);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with the data but be weary of line breaks and other formatting that can mess with your array and intended use.  The first method may give you an array element of a space.  Use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
preg_match_all('/([\w]+)([\,\.])?/', "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",$match);

$arr = array_merge($match[1],array_filter($match[2]));
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preg_match_all()` without any capture groups or lookarounds for best efficiency.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39c527dd9928b9a38ba3f50e81c519ab2cb1b36e))

```
$string='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';
var_export(preg_match_all('/[a-z]+|\S/i',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Lorem',
  1 => 'ipsum',
  2 => 'dolor',
  3 => 'sit',
  4 => 'amet',
  5 => ',',
  6 => 'consectetuer',
  7 => 'adipiscing',
  8 => 'elit',
  9 => '.',
)
```

`\w` can be used to match `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_` but in your sample only letters exist.

If you are including apostrophes, you can use `$pattern='/[a-z\']+|\S/i'` but future adjustments are decisions for you to make.

The `\S` in the second alternative is any non-whitespace character -- this collects all of the punctuation characters (one at a time) that the first alternative lets through.

The `i` flag on the pattern dictates that `[a-z]` will act like `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @locobastos did you see my efficient, single-function solution?  This is a professional grade solution.